# Using C++ Boost library how to return the number of seconds since 00:00:00 January 1, 1901 GMT?

Tags: c++11, unix, boost

The `seconds()` method should call from `main` method and it should print the format of `00:00:00 January 1, 1901 GMT` and it should return(calculate) number of seconds elapsed till user input time, I am new to the C++, I tried a lot but not able to make it happen

The code i tried:

```
// here i tried to start the day from the mentioned date and time
boost::posix_time::ptime timeObj = boost::posix_time::time_from_string("1901/01/01 00:00:00");

 // Get current system time
boost::posix_time::ptime timeLocal = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

boost::posix_time::time_duration durObj = timeLocal.time_of_day();
std::cout << "Seconds : = " << timeLocal.time_of_day().seconds() << std::endl;
```

after this

1. I need to get a difference of seconds from `00:00:00 January 1, 1901 GMT` to user input time.
2. in front of it should returns the format of `00:00:00 January 1, 1901 GMT`.

I am doing this because I am customizing this boost library for our own product use.

Comment: Using Boost to get seconds since an arbitrary date is massive overkill, like using dynamite as a flyswatter.  [POSIX `time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/time.html) already provides seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  Just wrap it with your own function and add a fixed value to that, converting to a 64-bit value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use time_of_day (because it gives the time-of-day).

Don't use seconds but total_seconds.

Use ptime arithmetic to get the difference. The rest was fine.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec1f370b47d3c4b4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

size_t foo() {
    boost::posix_time::ptime epoch { { 1901, 1, 1 } };

    auto diff = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() - epoch;
    return diff.total_seconds();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << "\n";
}
```

Which printed:

```
3710416481
```

Which should enable you to determine my average typing speed and my local timezone :)

Comment: Is it possible to give user input time instead of  local_time() ?.